# JQuery does not seem to be loading properly and causing an error?

Tags: jquery, html

I have been looking at the console errors of a site I am working on and notice something I don't understand:

> TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function
>
> $('.stick-header').waypoint('sticky', {

I read that this may be caused by `JQuery` being loaded twice and so looked into that. My line loading JQuery was this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>
```

Again, more reading suggested that I should not be loading the latest version and so I replaced the 'latest' `JQuery` call with this (from https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/?hl=en):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Now I get two errors, and a carousel at the bottom of the page no longer loads.

> TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function
>
> $('.stick-header').waypoint('sticky', {
>
> TypeError: a.replace is not a function
>
> ...b)):c(a))},camelCase:function(a){return > a.replace(p,"ms-").replace q,r)},nodeNam...

The new error is from from jquery.min.js. Can anyone explain what might be causing either or both?

The order of scripts being loaded:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/menu-script.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/custom.js?ver=10.2.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js?ver=10.2.4'></script>
```

Comment: what all scripts you have loaded and in which order? Can you be more detailed on that and where you have initialized this `waypoint`?

Comment: I think it might be more likely that your selector didn’t match any elements … do a `console.log($('… your selector …').length)` and see what you get.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao - thanks. See edited question. And Waypoint is called in custom.js

Comment: Where is `waypoint` function defined?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao it's a plugin but he is not loading the corresponding lybrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waypoint is not a jquery functionality but it is an indipendent library that you have to load after you load jquery (only once in the page please!).
After you load jquery you can do:

```
<script src="/path/to/waypoint"></script>
```

and then you can use its functionalities.

The error you see is thrown by jQuery that is working right but when it comes to understand what to do when it finds `.waypoint(` it doesn't know.

On the point about the "latest" jquery it is better to use the stable release to keep your code stable and reliable too. That's why you found that suggestion

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is the site does not load properly unless I use the Latest version.

Comment: probably the latest version contains some changes in the syntax compared to the previous version and to use the previous versions you have to fix something in your code. Eg. deprecated functionalities that have been removed... We should have a look at the errors to understand what is the issue in that case

Answer (score 1):

Multiple jQuery loading removes 3rd party connections between jQuery and them. You need the remove second one.

Comment: I didn't add a second. I replaced the first with the second.

Comment: np. at the end there should be one.

Comment: Sorry - I don't understand what you mean

Comment: firstly you need load jquery then 3rd party plugin.

Comment: .waypoint's js reference must be load after jquery. after waypoint you must not load jquery again.